# How to save a keyboard macro as a Lisp function?

Tags: elisp, keyboard-macros

Very frequently I would need to perform the set of steps requiring multiple key strokes. For the same session those steps can be recorded in a keyboard macro.

An example is saving a frequently executed search/replace operation as a keyboard macro. But that macro is lost when I quit emacs.

How can I save my frequently used keyboard macro as a Lisp function?

For the sake of simplicity, I want to save the action of replacing "abc" with "def" as a function so that I can reuse it across emacs sessions.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here are the steps that you can follow:

- Select the region you want to do the search-replace.
- Start recording macro.

  `M-x start-kbd-macro`
- Do the required `M-x query-replace-regexp` (replace "abc" with "def") and use `!` to force search-replace in the whole region.
- Stop recording macro.

  `M-x kmacro-end-or-call-macro`.
- Do `M-x kmacro-name-last-macro` and give the macro a descriptive name like `replace-abc-with-def`. You will then be able to call that macro again by doing `M-x replace-abc-with-def`.
- Now save this macro as a function to a file that you load during your emacs initialization; for example, `init.el`.

  - `M-x insert-kbd-macro`
  - Select your named macro to be inserted there.

The auto-created `replace-abc-with-def` function definition looks like this:

```
(fset 'replace-abc-with-def
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([59 39 return 97 98 99 return 100 101 102 return 33] 0 "%d")) arg)))
```

Now you can `M-x replace-abc-with-def` in all your emacs sessions.

Comment: +1 for `insert-kbd-macro`. That is the answer to the question (and the rest of this answer provides additional help).

Comment: Note also that Emacs can generate two different formats for keyboard macros. Which one you get when you `insert-kbd-macro` depends upon whether you named it using `kmacro-name-last-macro` (as in the above answer) or `name-last-kbd-macro`.

Comment: Note that if you use the `name-last-kbd-macro` format (as mentioned by @phils above) you end up with a string, not a function. `fset`ting that to a symbol lets you execute the macro using M-x, but *not* call it from lisp (`commandp` -> `t`, `functionp` -> `nil`). Strangely, even calling it via `call-interactively` doesn't work (although you *can* use `execute-kbd-macro` to run it).

Answer (score 28):

[elmacro](https://github.com/Silex/elmacro) was already mentioned by @lunaryorn, but as the author of this package I thought it'd be nice to provide an example.

If you record a macro like this:

<kbd>F3 C-e M-b M-u C-a C-n F4</kbd>

Then doing <kbd>M-x elmacro-show-last-macro upcase-last-word</kbd> produces a buffer with:

```
(defun upcase-last-word ()
  "Change me!"
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line 1)
  (backward-word 1)
  (upcase-word 1)
  (move-beginning-of-line 1)
  (next-line 1 1))
```

Answer (score 18):

The [elmacro](https://github.com/Silex/elmacro) package lets you view the last recorded macro as proper Emacs Lisp with <kbd>M-x elmacro-show-last-macro</kbd>.

Comment: Someone recommending my package \o/