# Insert saved macro

Tags: elisp-macros, prelude

I created a new macro and saved to `.emacs/init.el`:

```
(fset 'foobar
   [?f ?o ?o return ?b ?a ?r return])
```

How can I use this macro after restarting emacs?

Comment: [Related](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/71/115)

Comment: @Dan thank you for being aware, but I don't agree on marking this as a duplicated. **The question is not the same**, although the solution is pointed out in other SE answer.

Comment: @kaushalmodi thank you, it's related indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run that macro with `M-x foobar`.