# How to get to my day page with one key

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-agenda

To get to my day page (agenda), currently I have to type in the following keys

1. `C-c a` (binded to `(org-agenda)`)
2. `a`     (Agenda for current week or day)
3. `d`     (to switch from week-view to day-view)
4. `C-c C-x C-c` (to switch to column-view)

It's too much! Can I achieve the same thing by pressing just one key say `<f10>`, and hopefully without unnecessary evaluations? It's not as easy as normal key bindings I suppose, since one has to deal with the org agenda dispatcher.

#### EDIT: Answer found

1. See NickD's answer. The key is `(org-agenda-list nil nil 1 nil)` and details can be found in the manual of the function `(org-agenda-list)` by `C-h f org-agenda-list <RET>`. This way is much faster than the second answer below.
2. If you accept macro as a solution (which is slower), turn it into an elisp function by using the package `elmacro` and assign a keybind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own function that does all the things you want it to do and bind it to a key:

```
(defun my-day-page ()
   (interactive)
   (org-agenda-list nil nil 1 nil)
   (org-agenda-columns))

(define-key global-map [f10] 'my-day-page)
```

See the doc for org-agenda-list (`C-h f org-agenda-list RET`) for the meaning of the arguments: the third argument (the 1 above) is the span (i.e. how many days this list should cover).

Comment: Super! That's exactly what I'm looking for. It makes the workflow much faster by not evaluating unnecessary functions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be a macro, more information can be found on the [emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros), but essentially all you would do is:

1. `C-x (`

   - Start Recording a Macro
2. `C-c a a C-c C-x C-c`

   - Open the Agenda in column view
3. `C-x )`

   - End the Macro
4. `M-x name-last-kbd-macro my-day-page`

   - Give the macro a name
5. `M-x insert-kbd-macro`

   - Insert the Macro
6. `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") 'my-day-page)`

That macro function and keybinding can now be added to your `~/emacs.d/init.el` file and pressing `C-c b` should now open up the day-page.

All together it might look like this:

```
;; Macro for Day View
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") 'org-agenda)
(fset 'my-day-page
(kmacro-lambda-form [?\C-c ?a ?a ?\C-c ?\C-x ?\C-c] 0 "%d"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") 'my-day-page)
```

#### -- EDIT by OP --

If you want to see what a macro is really doing, use the package [elmacro](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70/how-to-save-a-keyboard-macro-as-a-lisp-function), which turns your macro into a elisp function. In your case, after installation of `elmacro` from `melpa`, run `elmacro-mode`.

Define the macro as usual `<f3>C-c a a d R C-c C-x C-c<f4>`, and run the magical `M-x elmacro-show-last-macro`. It will generate a buffer with the elisp function!

```
(defun last-macro ()
  (interactive)
  (org-agenda-list nil)
  (org-agenda nil)
  (org-agenda-day-view nil)
  (org-agenda-clockreport-mode)
  (org-agenda-columns))
```

Please note that this result is not completely satisfactory. You want to get rid of `(org-agenda nil)` from the function, ending up give you

```
(defun the-macro-you-like ()
  (interactive)
  (org-agenda-list nil)
  (org-agenda-day-view nil)
  (org-agenda-clockreport-mode)
  (org-agenda-columns))
```

Finally, put this function in your config file, and bind it to `<f10>` for example by

`(global-set-key (kbd "<f10>") 'the-macro-you-like)`

Comment: Thank you. Still two more things are concerning.. 1. Are there other ways to circumvent org-agenda dispatcher, so it can be more scriptable? 2. A macro runs a risk when I happen to be in some other mode where the key-chords are mapped to other dangerous commands. Are there ways to be make it safer?

Comment: A1. To make it more scriptable, use `elmacro`, which turns a macro into an elisp function. It might not be perfect everytime, see my edition to the answer.